# Android: After import libs start to have error "cannot find symbol method getContext" & "getColor" etc

Tags: android

when I try to integrate with my friend android-project and need to import my libs folder however the application start to have "errror:cannot find symbol method getContext". Anyone got idea what is happening ?

When I remove these code , the file will work properly. However my another project when import these libs doesn't have any problem.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4-r13.jar')
    compile files('libs/indoors-library-surface.jar')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0'

}
```

Comment: show your code where getting this error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check your directory structure or post your code might be you missing something that not letting you to build gradle